# QCameras reduced performance

Tags: c++, performance, qt, camera

I need to create a lot of qcameras.
If there are more than 4 cameras, the video starts glitching but the system load isn't too high:
cpu<5%
ram>4gb
And it happens, even I launch the camera without the viewFiender.

How to add additional cameras?
What resources does qcamera consume?

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    videoItems[i]=new QGraphicsVideoItem;
    videoItems[i]->setSize(QSize(x,y));
    videoItems[i]->setOffset(QPointF(x*col,y*row));
    scene->addItem(videoItems[i]);
    camera[i]=new QCamera(source);
    camera[i]->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureViewfinder);
    camera[i]->setViewfinderSettings(setting);
    camera[i]->setViewfinder(videoItems[i]);
    camera[i]->start();
    col++;
    if(col==columns)
    {
        col=0;
        row++;
    }
}
```